# What can be alternate source of input for args getResolvedOptions() method in AWS GlueJob?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have a Glue Job in which I want to pass parameters to `getResolvedOptions`. One way I know is by creating a JobRun within Lambda Function, I can pass it. What are the other ways to pass `param1` and `param2` in code below:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['param1',
                                     'param2'])
```

*Note: I don't want to pass parameters in code by hardcoding it.*

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could create your gluejob through cloudformation and specify the DefaultArguments parameter which can be retrieved through getResolvedOptions

Comment: @pkarfs Can you help me with passing parameters using Workflows?

Comment: Workflows as in cloudformation templates for resource and script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this through [cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html#cfn-glue-job-securityconfiguration) (cfn) yaml templates or alternatively you could just add the variables directly to the job, via cli/sdk/console etc. If you wanted to go down the cfn route, you could define your resource as follows:

```
  JobNAME:
    Type: "AWS::Glue::Job"
    Properties:
      Name: String
      Description: String
      Role: String
      GlueVersion: 1.0
      Command: 
        Name: "glueetl"
        ScriptLocation: String
        PythonVersion: 3
      DefaultArguments: {
          "--job-language": "python",
          "--param1" : VALUE,
          "--param2" : VALUE,
          "--TempDir" : String,
          "--job-bookmark-option" : "job-bookmark-enable",
          "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log" : "false",
          "--enable-continuous-log-filter" : "false",
          "--enable-metrics" : "false"
      }
      ExecutionProperty:
        MaxConcurrentRuns: 1
      MaxCapacity: 5
      MaxRetries: 1
      Timeout: 60
```

Once defined, you can call out the parameters through getResolvedOptions, noting there are reserved values for glue defaults, e.g.:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

## @params: [JOB_NAME <--default assigned, param1 <---your value, param2 <---your value]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'param1','param2'])
```